# Double title in NavigationItem with iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8

Why is the title doubled inside this NavigationItem? I'm running on iOS 8.

Here's a [partial screenshot](http://prntscr.com/4pupup):
[image: An image indicating the issue]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have a customized navigationbar and BarItems.

My solution was to use no deprecated keys for customizing (see this sample):

Use instead of this keys (keys are deprecated):

```
@{ UITextAttributeTextColor: [self navigationBarTextColor],
   UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:0.0],
   UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: @0 };
```

This:

NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
   [shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];

```
@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [self navigationBarTextColor],
   NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:0.0],
   NSShadowAttributeName: shadow };
```

I hope that it helps.